# Does Rails have a way to convert checkboxes from "on" to true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

When a controller receives the params of a checked checkbox it comes back as "on" if the box was checked. Now in my case I'm trying to store that value as a boolean, which is typically what you want to with values from checkboxes. My question is, does rails have a way to automatically convert "on" (or even exists) to true/false or do I need to do the following?

```
value = params[my_checkbox] && params[my_checkbox] == "on" ? true : false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
value = !params[:my_checkbox].nil?
```

as the checkbox would not return any value if not checked (implied by this [forum](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=37736))

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is to create a custom setter for the field in the database, something like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def active=(value)
    value = value == 'on' ? true : false   
    super(value)
  end
end
```

That way you don't have to worry about it in the controller and it's the model that knows what value it is supposed to be. When you go to the view rails automatically checks a checkbox from a boolean field. Just in case that didn't work you could also define your own getter.

This can be then used for example in conjunction with store accessor something like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :active, inclusion: {in: [true, false]}
  validates :remember_password, inclusion: {in: [true, false]}

  store :settings,
        accessors: [:active, :remember_password],
        coder: JSON

  def active=(value)
    value = value == 'on' ? true : false   
    super(value)
  end

  def remember_password=(value)
    value = value == 'on' ? true : false   
    super(value)
  end
end
```

Note that the setting field in the database has to be text so you can put more stuff in it.